Spherical Shell Heatmap
I am following the script of an answer to this question to plot a heatmap over a sphere using the SmoothDensityHistogram[] function. The data is a text file of N rows by 3 columns, with each column corresponding to x, y, and z positions confined to the surface of a sphere of arbitrary radius.
vecs = Import["C:\\...\\testing_3d_mathematica_v1.txt", "Table"];

hist = Image[ SmoothDensityHistogram[vecs, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotRange -> {{-π, π}, {0, π}}, 
PlotRangePadding -> None], ImageResolution -> 256];

ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[θ] Sin[φ], Sin[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[φ]}, {θ, -π, π}, {φ, 0, π}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Texture[hist]]

I am receiving a "not a valid dataset or list of datasets" error. I try Flatten[vecs] but this results in an empty plot of a sphere with no histogram texture. I also suspect the axes limits are incorrect, but I'm not sure how to adapt this code to function with my data.
Attached are a few lines of data:
22.03   15.85   22.09
-7.39   2.68    34.10
-3.11   0.82    34.85
5.04    -6.17   34.08

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Can you please edit the question include a few lines from your file testing_3d_mathematica_v1.txt, so that we can try to reproduce your problem?

What's this have to do with "4D"?

Sorry, I'll edit the title. 4D was meant to describe that the plot is made up of three-dimensional positions with each having a weight.

How big is your data?

SmoothDensityHistogram is expecting a list of {x,y} points, from which it constructs a histogram, not {x,y,z} points.

@azerbajdzan it's about 10,000 x 4, but the length may be larger or smaller depending on data collection

@Zachary Why "x 4"? You wrote its triples x, y, z.  Can you upload the data somewhere so that it is possible to download it.

@azerbajdzan - sorry, typo. The data is N x 3. I'll upload in a couple of days. Thanks.

@azerbajdzan - I've included a link to data through Dropbox.

@Zachary Don't you have a better data? It will be just a small disk of one color on a sphere of another color.

currently, yes. Future data may have different features.

This might be helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658889/location-of-highest-density-on-a-sphere.

First of all it is a fake density plot (like most (if not all) of the posts in your link in OP) since density computed in 2D and then wrapped around a sphere is not same as if the density was computed straight on a sphere.
If you know a formula how to compute density straight on a sphere you can post it in a comment and I will redo the plots with that formula.
Secondly I used a logarithmic depiction because your data is such that without logarithm it would look only like a single disk of one color on a sphere of other color.
data = ImageData[Import["https://i.sstatic.net/UDaNRjtE.png"], 
      "Byte"] // Flatten // FromCharacterCode // Uncompress;
pdata = ToPolarCoordinates[data][[All, {2, 3}]];

Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 35], Point[data]}, Boxed -> False]

hist = SmoothDensityHistogram[pdata, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotPoints -> 200, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend["M10DefaultDensityGradient", Log[100 # + 1]/
      4.6] &), PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> None]

SphericalPlot3D[1, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[hist], Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False]





Data stored in image:


This is great -- thanks so much.

I assume the second image you posted is "https://i.sstatic.net/UDaNRjtE.png". How is this generated from the text file?
